# Adding tooltip at input, angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following Problem: I have an input field, but it only works without the tooltip, with the tooltip I get undefined.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="DiskPermissions" class="col-md-3 m-x-auto" tooltip='Permissions "Disk"'>
<input type="text" ng-model="DiskPermissions" class="col-md-3 m-x-auto">
```

Controller:

```
var diskToAdd={ size: $scope.DiskSizeGB , mountepoint:'/appl/' + $scope.MountPoint , permissions: $scope.DiskPermissions , options: $scope.DiskOptions , owner: $scope.DiskOwner , filesystemType: $scope.DiskFilesystemtype , diskPart: ''};
```

Comment: is `tooltip` a directive?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can format your code by indenting it with four spaces, or just select it and click the `{}` button.

Comment: I'm not sure of what is tooltip ( if its your own directive or a tierce js lib ) but you can add the module 'ui.bootstrap' which provide very nice tooltip and use it with these directives : tooltip-placement="top-right" uib-tooltip="I'm a tooltip"

Answer (score 6):

The attribute isn't called `tooltip`, it's called `title`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="DiskPermissions" class="col-md-3 m-x-auto" title='Permissions "Disk"'>
```

Comment: On my page it is called tooltip

Comment: So is it a directive?

Comment: its the html tooltip attribute. And if i have the tooltip attribute I can see it, so that works, but somehow the ng-model is undefined if i use the tooltip ;(

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no such thing as a "HTML `tooltip` attribute". The attribute used for displaying tooltips [is called `title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title).

Comment: hmm ok now i get your first answer. I will try it out with title.

Comment: well with the title attribute it works, but with the 'title' the tooltip is a grey line. With 'tooltip' (I am using bootsrap) the tooltip is a fancy dark field, which would be better

Answer (score 1):

You can try [matTooltip](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview) as:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="DiskPermissions" class="col-md-3 m-x-auto" matTooltip='Permissions "Disk"'>
```